# Create @TableName dynamically with number based on loop number

Tags: sql, t-sql

so I have a while loop and inside the loop, I want to create tables based on how many loops the sql has done. For example, @TableName1, @TableName2, @TableName3 and so on. A sample of the code below shows what I needed:

```
Declare @LoopCounter int =1
Declare @TotalCount int =10
While (@LoopCounter < @TotalCount)
BEGIN
Declare @TableName + (select @LoopCounter) TABLE(
);
END
```

Comment: Whatever you think of trying to accomplish, creating table variables in loop is probably not the correct approach.

Comment: I totally agree with Nenad Zivkovic - This has [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) written all over it. Creating multiple table variables with the same structure in a loop is definitely, without even a hint of a doubt, the wrong solution to whatever problem you try to solve.

Comment: first of all, I'll need different tables to differentiate each other. Like first table contain something and second table contains something first table don't have.

secondly, my program is about sorting stuff and it needs to be very dynamic, and the @TotalCount is provided by how many items I have in my inventory. So if I have 3 category, I will need to create 3 tables, if I have 15, I'll need to create 15. I cannot create it manually as I'm creating a stored procedure

Comment: Instead of different tables, you can do that by creating one table and adding LoopCounter column. Later you can distinguish your data based on that column.

Comment: And to answer the starting question: It's not possible. In order to create dynamic tables you need dynamic sql. But, if you create table variable or temp table inside dynamic sql it will exists only inside that dynamic sql. You can't see it outside.